# An error has occurred: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, json

I'm trying to update a record with JQuery/JSON but I'm seeing this error:

> An error has occurred:
>
> [object Object]
>
> parsererror
>
> SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character

**My JS:**

```js
jQuery('#commentForm').live('submit', function (event) {
event.preventDefault()

    
jQuery.ajax(edit_url, {
    data: jQuery(this).serialize(),
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'POST',
    success: function (data) {
        if (data.error === 'OK') {
            alert('ok c good')
        } else {
            alert('hi' + data.error)
        }
    },
    error: function(x,y,z){
        alert('An error has occurred:\n' + x + '\n' + y + '\n' + z);
    }
})
    
return false;
})
```

**And my php:**

```php
$ret = array(
    'error'             =>  'OK',
);
$update =
    "UPDATE crm_set_users SET ".
        "crm_set_users_civilite = '".mysql_real_escape_string($crm_set_users_civilite)."',".
        "crm_set_users_nom = '".mysql_real_escape_string($crm_set_users_nom)."',".
        "crm_set_users_prenom = '".mysql_real_escape_string($crm_set_users_prenom)."',".
        "crm_set_users_email = '".mysql_real_escape_string($crm_set_users_email)."', ".
        "crm_set_users_telephone = '".mysql_real_escape_string($crm_set_users_telephone)."', ".
        "crm_set_users_portable = '".mysql_real_escape_string($crm_set_users_portable)."'";
        
if($crm_set_users_photo != ""){
    $update .=", crm_set_users_photo = '".mysql_real_escape_string($crm_set_users_photo)."'";
}   
    
$update .=
    "WHERE ".
        "crm_set_users_id = '".mysql_real_escape_string($user_id)."'";




echo json_encode($ret);
exit;
```

If my php is :

```php
$ret = array(
    'error'             =>  'OK',
);
echo json_encode($ret);
exit;
```

then it works...

Tks for you help!

Comment: Check your output in a hex editor (NOT in the browser), some garbage before or after (particularly utf-8 BOM) could be the cause.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Did you know that you only have to write `jQuery` in its long form once? By wrapping your code in `(function($) { .... })(jQuery);`, you can use `$` no matter if `noConflict` has been used or not.

Comment: Also, since you have just 1 element you may remove that comma.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably your PHP throws some Errors or Warnings, which make the returned document not a valid JSON string. Use a debugger like [FireBug](http://getfirebug.com/) to see, what actual result is returned by your PHP script.

Following the PHP docu for `mysql_real_escape_string` ([link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php))it will throw an Error, if there is no active MySQL connection available. Maybe that's your problem.

Answer (score 3):

The problem must be that the php to update the record fails, and so the json does not get outputted.

I think you need to add a space before the `WHERE`

```
$update .=
    " WHERE ".
```

to give it some room after the rest of the string

Comment: This might be correct, but in the source given the SQL query is never sent to the MySQL server. Thus this should not be the reason for the error.